# Согласование географических названий с родовым наименованием

Tags: грамматика, склонение, названия

Здравствуйте! Как я понимаю, по правилам необходимо склонять названия рек и озер, если род совпадает и названия не являются экзотическими, т. е. реки Великой, реки Волги, озера Остречья. В профессиональной среде часто употребляется без согласования, допустимо ли?. И как быть в случае составных названий, например, река Нижняя Сума? Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правило гласит: Названия **р е к**, как правило, согласуются с родовым наименованием, например: на реке Днепре(также: на Москве-реке); между реками Обью и Енисеем.   Малоизвестные названия рек, особенно иноязычные, обычно не согласуются: на реке Рось; у реки Птичь;бассейн реки Аргунь; в долине реки Гильменд; на реке Меконг. То же часто при **составных** названиях: приток реки Голая Долина; на реке Чёрная Вольта (но в соответствии с правилом: на реке Северной Двине).

Названия **о з е р, з а л и в о в, п р о л и в о в, к а н а л о в, б у х т, о с т р о в о в, п о л у о с т р о в о в, г ор, г о р н ы х х р е б т о в, п у с т ы н ь и т. п.**, как правило, не согласуются с родовыми наименованиями,например: на озере Байкал (также: на Ильмень-озере); вблизи залива Аляска; в проливах Скагеррак и Каттегат; в бухте Золотой Рог; за островом Новая Земля; на острове Ява; на полуострове Флорида; у мыса Челюскин; на горе Эльбрус; над хребтом Куэнь-Лунь; в пустыне Каракум; у оазиса Шарабад; вблизи лунногократера Архимед; над вулканом Этна; извержение вулкана Везувий.

Как видите,правило допускает употребление названий рек в качестве несогласованного приложения,особенно малознакомых, а вот **названия озёр не склоняются** по правилу.

А в профессиональной среде - это учительской или среди литераторов? Литераторам, конечно, непростительно, а остальным - ничего страшного, но поправлять, я думаю, надо, ведь они пример для учеников.